# Comment giving away an already easy audit

Tags: discussion, review-queues, comments, review-audits

I got this audit in triage: https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/15975834
Which obviously is a spam post, however there is a comment on this post:

> best kind of spam!

which makes it even more obvious.

Should this comment be removed, or this entire question by itself?

On a side-note: if you fail this audit you should possibly be banned from ever reviewing anything ever again.

[image: audit]

Comment: Not necessarily as the point is that you notice the comment and take the appropriate action. A robo reviewer would probably miss it by spamming the _Looks OK_ button.

Comment: @Aziz Shaikh, that topic is about trics and exploits. This question more regards the design of the review process.

Comment: I understand your point but I believe that the answer given there covers this post as well. Lets see if the community agrees with the possible dupe or not.

Comment: According to the review history (only available to mods), you are the 8th person to have received this audit. Surprisingly, no one has failed this audit yet.

Comment: @BoltClock That's indeed quite a surprise, but good to hear. I wonder what would happen if a mod alters that comment to "Nice post, thanks!". Would people start to fail that audit?

Comment: @Tom that's not a bad idea